# Access to SmartCard with iText

Tags: java, itext, bouncycastle, smartcard, pkcs#11

I am testing electronic sign applications with a SmartCard D–TRUST certificate v 2.6.1.

I have developed a web service application that reads from the SmartCard, gets the availables SLOTS and the certificates with the purpose of signing documents.

I'm using Java, using iText(version 5.4.3) and BounceCastle (version 15on-1.48), but there is a problem when I am trying to get the availables slots: It returns 1000, 0 and 1 and when I want to access to the certificates, the application encountered a problem:

> Initialization failed in the method call
>   Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);

I use the library personal.dll, placed in C:\Program Files(x86)\Personal\

And the code in Java is :

```
public class SmartCard
{
    public static long[] getSlots (String libraryPath) throws IOException
    {
        CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS initArgs = new CK_C_INITIALIZE_ARGS();
        String functionList = "C_GetFunctionList";
        initArgs.flags = 0;
        PKCS11 tmpPKCS11 = null;
        long[] slotList = null;
        try
        {
            try
            {
                tmpPKCS11 = PKCS11.getInstance(libraryPath, functionList, initArgs, false);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        catch (PKCS11Exception e)
        {
            try
            {
                initArgs = null;
                tmpPKCS11 = PKCS11.getInstance(libraryPath, functionList, initArgs, true);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (PKCS11Exception ex)
            {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try
        {
            slotList = tmpPKCS11.C_GetSlotList(true);
            System.out.println("****  SLOTS  ****");
            System.out.println(String.format("Hay %d slots.", slotList.length));
            System.out.println("------");
            for (long slot : slotList)
            {
                CK_TOKEN_INFO tokenInfo = tmpPKCS11.C_GetTokenInfo(slot);
                System.out.println("slot: " + slot + "\nmanufacturerID: "
                                + String.valueOf(tokenInfo.manufacturerID)
                                + "\nmodel: " + String.valueOf(tokenInfo.model));
                System.out.println("----");
            }
        }
        catch (PKCS11Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            tmpPKCS11 = null;
        }

        return slotList;
    }

    public static String getCertificadosInfo(String numeroPIN, String namePkcs11, String nameLibreria, long slotID) throws Exception
    {
        String strRetorno = "";
        KeyStore ks = null;
        Provider providerPKCS11 = null;

        try
        {
            BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            Security.addProvider(providerBC);

            String strPass = numeroPIN;
            char[] pass = null;
            if (strPass != null)
                        pass = strPass.toCharArray();

            String configFilePath = String.Format("name=%s\nlibrary=%s\nslotListIndex=%d", namePkcs11, nameLibreria, slotID);
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(configFilePath.getBytes());

            providerPKCS11 = new SunPKCS11(bais);
            Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);  // HERE THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN: Initialization failed

            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
            ks.load(null, pass);

            boolean bNoHayCertificados = true;
            Enumeration<String> oEnum = ks.aliases();

            .......
```

Anybody knows what could be the problem?

Thanks a lot, I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi new user and welcome. Smartcard/PKCS#11 related questions are rather sparse here and there are not many *followers* of the given tags. So apologies for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the numbers returned. If you directly call the PKCS#11 module everything is fine. The number of available slots indicate the number of slots that *may* contain a token. As you can have any number of card readers, the number of slots is indeterminate. And you should not care, unless there is a token inside one of them.

It may be that you should not load the provider twice. You load it once directly in `getSlots`, then you let Sun PKCS#11 provider load it again. Otherwise, you should take a look at the Sun PKCS#11 logging to see why the `.dll` won't initialize. You can enable it by supplying `-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11,pkcs11` to your call to the VM/runtime (`java` or `javaw`).